# How to sync iCloud cal with Exchange

Tags: icloud, ical, exchange-activesync

I use an Exchange server for work email and calendar, and I use an iCloud/iCal calendar at home and freelance business.

I want to sync all my iCloud calendar items - not contacts, email or anything else.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The two services are not designed to easily merge with one another. There are numerous syncing tools available, but when you have multiple sync services interacting with each other (in this case: iCloud, middle man service & Exchange are each their own sync service) you dramatically increase the chance of serious sync corruptions.

As your goal is to see all of your calendars everywhere, I recommend setting up both services on all of your devices. You will want to use the following apps, depending on platform, for an ideal experience and visibility to both calendars:

- Mac: use Apple Calendar (formerly, iCal). See [this guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph4737) for setting up both account types.
- PC: use Outlook. See [this guide](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/pc.html) for setting up iCloud in Outlook. See [this guide](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/add-or-remove-an-e-mail-account-HA001231634.aspx) for setting up Exchange accounts in Outlook.
- iOS: See [this guide](http://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/ios.html) for setting up iCloud. See [this guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2480) for setting up Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible for you to sync the two calendars but its a bit of a convoluted process.

1. Install google apps sync and use that to sync your exchange with google calendar.
2. use something like SyncMate to sync google with iCloud.

Don't know how effective this is but it may be your best option.

(iCloud will apparently sync with a standalone version of outlook out of the box)

Comment: Does this not assume the user is an osx based iCloud user?

Answer (score -3):

There really isn't any need to sync the Exchange and iCloud calendars together. All you have to do is add both calendars to iCal, iOS or on the Mac, and you will see all of those events.

Comment: yes there is, i cannot see my personal events on exchange server, at work. Hence why I asked the question.

Comment: Sorry Graeme, I misunderstood. I thought you just wanted to be able to see all your events. I do what you're describing but I do it in iCal. I've added both iCloud and Exchange calendars and it works fine. Any reason not to do this in iCal and instead of in Exchange?

Comment: Yes, its a work PC

Comment: Time for an iPad?

Comment: got one, but it is not my work laptop.

Comment: A comment on the downvote would be nice. My answer is correct if using Apple hardware/software.

Comment: Its wrong for this question then isn't it?

Comment: Wrong for this question only after our exchange where we determined that your requirements are to use a PC and Exchange as the platform for viewing these events. Perhaps the question should be more specific. If Exchange is capable of subscribing to a subscribed calendar you could try to _Publish_ your iCal calendar and then subscribe in Exchange. Sorry, I looking for a solution for you but didn't realize the requirements till later in the comments.